# C# Calling data from DB and using it in a Button Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, webforms

Basically I've got a Database that stores System Information

1. System Id
2. SystemName
3. SystemDescription
4. System Path

Now the System Path will be filled by an administrator with the path of an aspx page related to that System.

My question here is, could I have a button next to my SqlDataSource table related to the systems in my DB that on Click will take the System Path and go to it, so if you click on System1's View button you'll be directed to ~/pages/system1.aspx

--- ERRORS ---

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Multiple controls with the same ID 'LinkButton1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.]
   System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls) +233
   System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls) +311
   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset) +304
   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset) +412
   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset) +412
   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset) +412
   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset) +412
   System.Web.UI.Page.FindControl(String id) +38
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1960
```

Comment: can you be more clear in your question

Comment: Please format the question properly.. we are unable to makeout clearly.

Comment: It is very unclear as to what your asking from this question. Is it right to assume the path filled in by the administrator is queried with 'System Path' To retrieve all Systems with that path? then what exactly do you need the button for?

Comment: @Harvey Basically The Admin will input the Path to the aspx page related to that system, so that the USER can access the Page of the System by clicking on the 'VIEW' button

Comment: Why have you got multiple buttons for this? One button called "View.." is all you would need.  A user could select the record to reference the correct "System Path"

Comment: I tried to use SQL buttons for Insert,edit,delete,view of the SqlDataSource...

Comment: @Harvey In the GridView1_SeletedIndexChanged method I did a reponse,redirect to my aspx page however now, whenever I click ANY 'Select' next to my Systems they all redirect to the same page, how can I change this ?

Comment: You need the attribute 'SelectedItem' Not the method 'Selected Changed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `SystemId` is primary key. The idea is to GET `SystemId` of that row when you click on `View` to pass it to the url you want to redirect to.

aspx page using gridview:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" DataKeyNames="SystemId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="SystemId">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSystemId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SystemId") />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="SystemName">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("SystemName") %>' runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="SystemDescription">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" Text='<%# Eval("SystemDescription") %>' runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SystemId")%>'
                                                                ToolTip="Click to view this system" OnClick="lbtView_Click">View</asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>

                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YOUR-CONNECTIONSTRING-IN-WEB.CONFIG %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SYSTEM"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void lbtView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    LinkButton lbtView = (LinkButton)sender;
                    string SystemID = lbtView.CommandArgument;
                    Response.Redirect("/pages" + SystemID + ".aspx");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Exeption message
                    lblMessage.Text = "An error has occurred. Please try again later!</br><i>" + ex.Message + "</i>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Page validation failed. Please try again!";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now  Line 27:       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
Line 28:         <ItemTemplate>
Line 29:           <asp:LinkButton ID="btnView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SystemId")%>'
Line 30:             ToolTip="Click to view this system" OnClick="lbtView_Click">View</asp:LinkButton>
Line 31:         </ItemTemplate>

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.pages_viewsystems_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'lbtView_Click' and no extension method 'lbtView_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.pages_viewsystems_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I didn't fully test my code but the idea is using CommandArgument to get the SystemID,  please post all codes in your .aspx page and c# code behind then maybe we can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Here is a breakdown of the button logic:

**OnClick Event:**

- Get currently selected record (e.g Called: SystemRecord)
- Navigate to the Path `Response.Redirect(SystemRecord.System Path)`

Comment: Can you explain in code how I can actually do this please?

Comment: This would be tough without knowing your design. But you reference SQLDataSourceTable's 'SelectedItem' Attribute. This will get you the currently selected record. After here you can reference the field attributes of the record. i.e. the System Path

Comment: check the edit I did to the question... I got that error now